# How can I use Jinja to create/populate a table in a Word document?

Tags: python, list, dataframe, jinja2, python-docx

I am attempting to turn my Pandas DataFrame into a table in a word document (.docx). I am using Jinja so I can control what table gets populated in the document since there are several.

However, I am unable to properly populate the table. With the code below I get three blank rows, rather than the data in the lists.

How can I properly populate the table? Is it an issue with the structure of the `improvementDict` or is it the Jinja?

```py
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate

doc = DocxTemplate("weekly-report-template.docx")

# New DataFrame with improvement issue type
improvementDF = excel_file.loc[excel_file["Issue Type"] == "Improvement"]

# Create lists out of each column
improvementKeys = improvementDF['Issue key'].tolist()
improvementTitles = improvementDF['Summary'].tolist()
improvementNotes = improvementDF['Custom field (RelNote Description)'].tolist()

# Create a dictionary from the lists above
improvementDict = {"improvKey":improvementKeys,"improvTitle":improvementTitles,"improvNotes":"N/A"}

# Populate the word doc (docx)
fill_content = {'improvementTable': improvementDict }
doc.render(fill_content)
doc.save('TEST.docx')
```

Here is the structure of the `improvementDict`:

```py
{'improvKey': 
 ['E-1234',
  'E-1235',
  'E-1236'],

 'improvTitle': 
 ['Test Title 1',
  'Test Title 2',
  'Test Title 3'],

 'improvNotes': 
 [' ',
  ' ',
  ' ']}
```

Hence, I would expect 3 rows with the keys in the first column, the title in the middle column, and the notes in the last column. Screenshots below:

[Jinja on the word document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpjSd.png)

[Result I get with current logic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTl1W.png)

[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYJXS.png)

I have tried the following:

- Attempted to flatten improvementDict lists

  - I thought maybe this was why I would sometimes see `improvKey` `improvTitle` and `improveNotes` take up the table space, rather than the data.
- I have gotten the data to populate before, but it would all take up one row rather than have a row for each entry in the list. I think the list itself was put in the row rather than the items in the list. Which makes me think the Jinja is the issue.

Comment: Hi Joe, you are very close. The structure of your input dict should be changed into records. You can use the following line to create data for your table: improvementDict = improvementDF.rename(columns={'Issue key':'improvKey','Summary':'improvTitle','Custom field (RelNote Description)':'improvNotes'}).to_dict('records')

Comment: @DickBos Wow! That worked! Thank you so much! Why is it that that worked? What about this data structure is different that what I was originally passing through?

Comment: [Here is a great resource for to_dict](https://www.w3resource.com/pandas/dataframe/dataframe-to_dict.php) -  I think I am grasping the difference in the data structure now, and why I was getting the output I was vs the correct output I get by using `to_dict('records')`